# android button: place android:text above the android:drawableBottom of a button

Tags: java, android

Is there a way I can place the text property above the android:drawableBottom property. This is my attempt

This is the screen shot of the below code

[image]

```
 <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/snap"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>
```

[image: I want to place the SCAN Text on top of the image]

**EDITTED**
This is the linearlayout showing how the group of buttons are placed in a horizontal orientation

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#338FD8D8"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="10px"
                android:paddingTop="10px">
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/snap"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/shutterButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:text="SNAP"></Button>

               <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/xxx"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:text="xxx"></Button>

               <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/xxx"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:text="xxx"></Button>


         </LinearLayout>
```

The above code does not place the SNAP text on top of the androidBottom property. Kindly assist

Comment: can you show any image exactly what you want..

Comment: Have added a screen shot. I am trying to place the SNAP text on top of the image of a button

Comment: @JnG When you format the xml code the properties will automatically setup down in xml file. You can't assume that i want text property first.

Comment: This little stuff is gradually looking complicated

Comment: @JnG Your xml code is already setting up the text above drawable what is wrong then.

Comment: The drawable dissappears. If you want I can show you screen shots

Comment: @JnG Yes please shoot your screen shot here exactly what you are getting with your xml code and what output you want.

Comment: Check to see screen shot

Comment: @JnG Try with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with this code.**

**Replace this code in your xml.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shutterButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_question_answer_black_36dp"
        android:text="SNAP"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here change your `Drawable` and `Text Color` and whatever `Background Color` you need.

**Screen shot here.**

[image]

**It will give you `Text` above drawable.**

**EDIT 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#338FD8D8"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_question_answer_black_36dp"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="SNAP"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_question_answer_black_36dp"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="xxx"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_question_answer_black_36dp"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="xxx"
            android:textColor="#000000" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**For Group of buttons screen shot here.**

[image]

Comment: Frankly, this does't work when placed among group of buttons in a linearlayout

Comment: @JnG I can't be able to get what you are saying ? what exactly you want now with group of buttons.

Comment: The above snippet is placed in a linear layout with group of buttons

Comment: @JnG Shoot your code in above question whatever you are trying with group of buttons and screen shot also.

Comment: I have editted my question to show how the buttons are placed in a linear layout with vertical orientation. Using the above, the text never appears on top of the choosen button

Comment: @JnG check my edited answer part and let me know is it working or not.

Comment: @JnG Screen shot added pls check.

Comment: @JnG Upvote and accept the answer if it is helpful to you thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

is it mandatory to use layout_weight in your xml ? if not, i think just remove that from your button in xml. it make your drawable and text mess up in your button if you have much view to add in your layout.

like this one :
if i just add 3 button in my layout, everything is run perfectly

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/shutterButton"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:text="SNAP"></Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/shutterButton1"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:text="SNAP"></Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/shutterButton2"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:text="SNAP"></Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/shutterButton4"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:text="SNAP"></Button>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentMain_RvTourList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

But if I add a lot of buttons and 1 recyclerview in my layout, the text and drawable in all buttons will be messy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton1"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton2"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton4"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton5"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton6"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton7"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton8"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/star_yellow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton9"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentMain_RvTourList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

if i change the orientation to be horizontal, the layout will be :

[image]

and the last, change your textcolor and background color on your button, avoid the same color for the both property.

Comment: Could you please make this to wrap_content to see what happens android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: Could you please also change your layout to horizontal

Comment: what about the first illustration

Comment: oh i forgot it, just see my answer